# Facebook for Android 3.0 use my own object instead of the built-in LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook

I followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/) tutorial that enables the facebook login without that long code described in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) tutorial (If I understand it correctly). The problem is that according to the tutorial it uses Facebook's LoginButton:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
```

which is

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

I want to use my own object. In my case I have a LinearLayout that the user can click on. How can I do this?

Comment: Use this library: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/) on the bottom of the page. This is a menu item of the actionbar but it could be a normal button as well:

```
menu_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();


                if (session != null && session.isOpened())  {
                     session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Session.openActiveSession(ViewPagerActivity.this, true, new StatusCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                            if (session.isOpened()) {

                              // make request to the /me API
                              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response with user object

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }
                              });
                            }
                          }
                        });
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample bit of code that logs in to Facebook and adds permission to publish to your wall.

```
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (currentSession == null
        || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
    Session session = new Session.Builder(this).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    currentSession = session;
}

if (currentSession.isOpened()) {

} else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
    OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(this);

    op.setCallback(statusCallback);

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("publish_stream");
    op.setPermissions(permissions);

    Session session = new Builder(this).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    session.openForPublish(op);
}
```

Facebook uses a `Session` to authenticate a user and manage the session, hence the name. There's a pretty detailed example bundled with the Facebook SDK called SessionLoginSample that you can take a look at.